# How to use VueGtag to track Google Ads conversions in Vue2 application

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to use VueGtag to track Google Ads conversions (signups) in Vue2 application.

I've added the following code to `main.js`:

```js
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag'
...
Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { id: 'AW-123456890AB' }
})
```

What code should I add to my signup callback function? The documentation is very sparse. Is it something like this?

```js
register() {
  ...
  this.$gtag.event('sign_up')
  ...
}
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
this.$gtag.event('conversion', {
    'send_to': 'TAG_ID/CONVERSION_LABEL', 
    'key': value
})
```

Make sure you add a config property with the tag id:

```
Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { id: "TAG_ID" },
  disableScriptLoad: true
});
```

Someone asked a similar question [in this issue](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag/issues/328) from the 'vue-gtag' package repository.